# redux-form not populating FieldArray with InitialValues object

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm working with react-redux-form 7.03 and attempting to populate fields from a database. In the interests of simplifying to determine where my issue is, I've created a static array of 1 object to try to get information to display.

I'm fairly new to React and Redux, and I've been fighting this for three days now.  I've been using the examples from https://codesandbox.io/s/qDjw3zGG and the redux-form examples with no luck.

Basic issue is that in the props, I'm seeing initialValue:xmlConfigDataSet with the correct information in the object (array with 1 object correctly filled in).  However that is not being passed to the fields property to RenderRows.  Debugging fields shows a length of 0 and it just passes over the map() and never renders.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class XMLMatchUpForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <FieldArray name="xmlConfigDataSet" component={RenderRows} />
        )
};

const RenderRows = ({fields, meta}) => (
    <div>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
            const value = fields.get(index);
            return <RenderStaticField name={field} value = {value} />
        })}
    </div>
)

const RenderStaticField = (props) => {
    <Field name={`${props.name}.MW_MD_VALUE`} component="input" />
}

XMLMatchUpForm =  reduxForm({
    form: "XMLMatchUpForm"
}) (XMLMatchUpForm);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        initialValues: {
            xmlConfigDataSet:[{"MW_XS_ID":1314,"MW_MD_ID":null,"MW_XDM_VALUE":"Silver Spring","MW_XS_TAG_NAME":"receivercity"}]
    }
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchXMLConfig}) (XMLMatchUpForm);
```

(ignore the {fetchXMLConfig} in the example, that is actually the action it is caling to get the xmlConfigDataSet, as I said above, I'm trying to simplify this to determine where the issue is.

Any ideas, or pointers to clear examples are welcome.

Comment: It would be nice if you prepare a sandbox with your code so we can help you

Comment: I am also facing similar kind of issue. Initial Values not updating in the field array. Can Some on help?